# How to tell which format is selected in the view in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have successfully setup the pdf format in Joomla 2.5 using [these instructions](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_PDF_views). There is some HTML that it is not very good at handling, the float css property for instance.

In my layout, I want to be able to give special directions when outputting as a pdf to account for this. The document format is set by adding `format=pdf` to the URL query string.

How do I determine which format is set from within my layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing it as query string try this

```
        $getformat = JRequest::getCmd('format');
```